# How to check if my service is playing audio in the background in Android?

Tags: android, audio, service

I have a service that plays a remote audio stream in the background via startForeground() and an ongoing notification. I'm having a problem letting my activity know if the audio is currently running so I can show either a play or a stop button.  Here's the onStartCommand call that starts the audio:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_PLAY)) {

        if(mMediaPlayer != null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            return START_STICKY;

        String url = intent.getStringExtra("live_url");
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return START_STICKY;
        }

        mMediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); // prepare async to not block main thread

        wifiLock = ((WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE))
                .createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "mylock");

        wifiLock.acquire();
    }
    else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_STOP)) {
        doRelease();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

and the onPrepared():

```
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {

    player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            doRelease();
        }
    });

    player.start();

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), REQUEST_CODE,
            new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityMain.class),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.playing_live))
            .setTicker("test")
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentIntent(pi);

    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a [Bound Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html).  That way your activity can call your service's methods, such as one you create which returns the value of your `mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()`.

Call the bound service's method from your activity's `onStart()` method to update your UI appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you look into the example code in the docs for [Bound Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder), you'll see a `getRandomNumber()` method that is meant for consumption of the client of the service.

That should give you an idea that you can define you own methods in the service class, typically wrapper methods in your case like below to solve your problem

```
public class MediaPlayerService extends Service{
  private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
  ..
  public boolean isPlaying() {
    return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
  }
}
```

Hope that helps. Cheers!